# ASR1K feature licensing navigation

Tags: cisco, bgp, bgp-ipv6, cisco-asr

I'm looking at deploying a pair of ASR1001 units at the WAN edge to support 2x IP Transit and 1x Peering services.

I need to do IPV4 and IPV6 eBGP and iBGP to advertise the peering routes into the core as the peering service will only be on one of the two units.

I'm having real trouble finding a succinct summary of the differences in available features between each feature license. Would anyone be able to either point me to an appropriate link or summarize what features are available from which feature set?

I have described the above scenario to a sales rep who has advised I need the Adv. Ent. Services feature set to unlock all functionality of BGP; but I'm somewhat suspicious of that recommendation...

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

For the ASR 1K, Advanced Enterprise Services is needed to support "legacy protocols" (IBM, IPX, etc.), but for IP protocols, including IPv6 and BGP, Advanced IP Services should be adequate. See the following links for more information.

- [Cisco IOS Packaging Customer Q&A](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/iosswrel/ps5460/products_qanda_item09186a00801af2c6.shtml)
- [Ordering ASR 1000 Software](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps9343/product_bulletin_c07-448862.html#wp9002584)
- [ASR 1000 router Q&A](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps9343/qa_c67-452124.html)

Comment: Advanced IP Services includes a roll-up of SP Services, including MPLS.

Comment: Thank you, however I couldn't find any specific references to BGP features between Adv. IP Svc. and IP Base in these links (i excluded the first link as it's referencing IOS rather than IOS XE.

Comment: Aside from platform specific features, IOS and IOS-XE code/license designations are the same. IOS-XE now uses the 15.x versioning scheme to reflect parity with IOS trains. IP Base is not going to have much, if any BGP support.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Feature Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/by-feature-technology.jsp) on Cisco's site.

I've found this to be the only way sometimes to compare which feature is available in each image/license level.

Choose the feature(s) you're looking for from the list at the left, then click continue.   After that you'll be able to drill down into the IOS-XE platform -> ASR1001.

You should be able to tell if you need Advanced Enterprise or Advanced IP there.

Comment: Thank you very much, however If i use the feature navigator, all features between Universal and Adv. Ent. Svc. (Adv. IP. is not in the list) appear as in common. I think this is because another document notes that all features are based on the honor system - which is lovely, but still doesn't tell me when i'm being dishonorable and when i'm being honorable... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take also IP Base license, IP Services only add other Features, including encryption (IPsec, 3DES, AES, and SSH), Lawful Intercept, and SBC.
The BGP features are included in the ASR1K-INTERNET Application Part Number, which offers ASR1000 Internet Edge/Peering - including BGP/NAT/ZBFW features, but it is something different than license (if you try to configure the router in CCW this item has no costs).
Check ordering guide for details